# HTML CSS Linear Gradient Can't Cover Height taller than viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in web dev. I apologize beforehand if my diction is not programmer-standard.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
1. multiple divs that can take any height. In this example, one has the height of the viewport, and the other one is taller (2000px).
2. 'body' element acts as the wrapper, which has a linear-gradient background that covers all divs areas.

Using some borders, I can see that the 'body' sizes itself accordingly to the 'div's inside it. However the gradient stops on the viewport height. Note: If I switch to a flat color, it works.

Here is my HTML (much simplified, but the point is still valid):

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(192, 196, 203, 1), rgba(42, 43, 44, 1));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid gold;
  /*just for visualizing area*/
}
#box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  /*viewport height, something I recently tried as an attempt to solve the problem*/
  border: 5px solid red;
  /*just for visualizing area*/
}
#box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  /*just for visualizing area*/
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id='box2'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `height` and `min-height` from the `body,html`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ujUwOCE/3/)**